# Can we get the control back to bot source after completion of composer dialog in the same turn

Tags: botframework, bots, bot-framework-composer

I am trying to use composer inside my Bot which is built on echo bot template, here I am trying to call the composer after executing some custom logic inside my bot and then handover the control to composer dialogs, here after completion of turn processing inside the composer dialogs, can we get the control back to bot code where I want to execute some other custom logic before ending my turn.

Adding the details as mentioned in the comments:

The composer dialogs gets triggered from an echo bot solution using this part of code

```
await dialogManager.OnTurnAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
```

Usually, whenever this line executes, the next lines after this line gets executed and the Composer Dialogs integrated in the solution are initiated after that, where the execution does not comes into code again.

So,  here my question is once the composer dialogs are processed in the same turn, I want the execution to come back into the code where I want to validate/process some custom login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended way to use custom code with Composer based bots is to either use a custom action or custom trigger and them implement those with in Composer. You can of course customize the runtime.

I'm not sure what you mean by:

> call the composer after executing some custom logic inside my bot and then handover the control to composer dialog

Are you customizing the Composer runtime? There is not enough information here to understand exactly what you are trying to accomplish. Please add code snippets and more specifics.